# Start ruby rake task on server boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, fedora, systemd

I have a couple of rails rake tasks that I need to start on server bootup. I have been looking to make them run as traditional services using systemd. The service file is created under `/etc/system/systemd` but unfortunately it looks like systemd did not find the file:

```
#systemctl start screens.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit screens.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status screens.service' for details.

#systemctl status screens.service
screens.service
      Loaded: error
      Active: inactive (dead)
```

I am currently using Fedora 15

How can I make my systemd service work? Is there another way I could make my rake tasks run at system boot.

**Update:** screens.service file content

```
[Unit]
Description=Send Reminders

[Service]
Type=simple
User=myuser
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/rails/app
ExecStart=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake reminders:send
```

I know that I need to set dependencies when I need it to work on bootup, but currently I am trying to start my rake using systemctl command and worry about it dependencies later.

Comment: Can we take a look at the `screens.service` file?

Comment: Is there any information in the systems log about what file or directory that it failed to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make systemd take notice of the newly added services I had to insert the following command:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 2):

First, instead of calling rake directly, I would call /path/to/ruby/bin/bundle exec rake my:raketask.

Second, I think you should really take a look at the foreman gem, as it's designed to handle this situation, though you might have to adapt it work with systemd.

One way would be to call foreman from systemd init file, passing it options to specify the Procfile (foreman config file) in your app's directory.

Foreman can already export its config to several formats, but I don't think yours is among them. But,
you could create a custom exporter that exports the foreman configuration to systemd format. See https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/wiki/Custom-exporters for more information. If you go this route, consider contributing your exporter back to the foreman project.

Comment: I was thinking of making it work with god (http://godrb.com/) but either way I have to make systemd work

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you need to start something in the application initializer, you could put the `.rb` file to

`config/initializers/` folder

Would you elaborate your requirement, because there might be some other way of doing the same? :)

Comment: I need to run 2 background processes that are independent of my application similar to delayed_jobs `rake jobs:work`

Comment: I need to run a method which can fetch credentials from Vault server while server start up and that should be available for the db look up and other processes just like initialising something using java @bean. Since I am new in Ruby, unable to figure out any way out to achieve this. any help would be appreciated.